# DIV positioning issue for side-by- side with auto width.

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have 2 DIVs. Something like below:

```
<div id="myForm" style="border: 1px solid black;width:500px;height:300px;margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <div><input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Type title here" style="width:auto;" /></div>
        <div><textarea name="desc" id="desc" placeholder="Type description here" style="width:auto;"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn">
        <div>
         <label style="text-align: right;">Owner:</label>
         <input type="text" name="owner" id="owner" style="width: 100px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label style="text-align: right;">Estimate:</label>
            <input type="text" name="estimate" id="estimate" style="width: 100px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then css I am using is given below:

```
.leftcolumn { width: auto; border: 1px solid red; float: left}
.rightcolumn { width: 200px; border: 1px solid red; float: right}
```

Given below a screenshot for the issue I'm facing:
[image]

Comment: Why not use `.leftcolumn { width: 300px;}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change css to:

```
.leftcolumn { width: auto; border: 1px solid red; margin-right: 204px;}
.rightcolumn { width: 200px; border: 1px solid red; float: right}
```

and replace right and left in html:

```
<div id="myForm" style="border: 1px solid black;width:500px;height:300px;margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="rightcolumn">
        <div>
            <label style="text-align: right;">Owner:</label>
            <input type="text" name="owner" id="owner" style="width: 100px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label style="text-align: right;">Estimate:</label>
            <input type="text" name="estimate" id="estimate" style="width: 100px;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <div><input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Type title here" style="width:auto;" /></div>
        <div><textarea name="desc" id="desc" placeholder="Type description here" style="width:auto;"></textarea></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UWPZ6/)

Comment: I want same width for the input elements inside the left div.

Comment: For this to work the `.rightcolumn` div needs to come before the `.leftcolumn` div in the HTML.

Comment: I have tried that but it's same not expanding the input width.

Comment: to expand the input, set its width to 100%

Comment: Sure, will do. Is there any way to make the textarea height to cover full height of the left DIV.

Comment: the left div must have a fixed height and then you can give the text area `height:100%`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a float for the left column, why not set the right margin to 200px (or 210px if you want some spacing);

```
.leftcolumn { margin-right: 210px; border: 1px solid red}
```

This will allow the right column to float into place within the margin.

You will also need to reverse the order of the divs in your html.  You want the right column to come before the left.  This will give you the fluid layout you want regardless of the width of "myForm".